# How to divide series of names into different rows

Tags: c#, regex, gridview, asp.net-4.0

I have a list of name in series like:

```
1.WROBEL/TERESA   2.WROBEL/MAREK
```

Now what i want is to show these name in grid like this

- WROBEL/TERESA
- WROBEL/MAREK

and so on i dont want number and . into grid.

how can i do that i am using asp.net4.0 web application

for example i have a string like this:

```
T-                                                                              
FXP/R,U                                                                         
 1.WROBEL/TERESA   2.WROBEL/MAREK                                             
 1   ORD LH  433 K 28AUG 1015P OK KKNC2N   CN10   28AUG28AUG 1PC                
 2 X FRA LH 1378 K 29AUG  405P OK KKNC2N   CN10   29AUG29AUG 1PC                
 3 O GDN LO  359 W 15SEP  800A OK KKNC2N   CN10   15SEP15SEP 1PC                
 4 X FRA LH  432 K 15SEP  530P OK KKNC2N   CN10   15SEP15SEP 1PC                
 ORD                                                                        
 FARE  U USD     174.00                                                          
 TX001 X USD   541.00YQAC TX002 X USD     5.50YCAE TX003 X USD    17.20USAP      
 TX004 X USD    17.20USAS TX005 X USD     5.00XACO TX006 X USD     7.00XYCR      
 TX007 X USD     2.50AYSE TX008 X USD    51.08RAEB TX009 X USD    17.16DESE      
 TX010 X USD     0.22NDAD TX011 X USD    14.78XWAE TX012 X USD     4.50XF        
 TOTAL   USD     857.14                                                          
 GRAND TOTAL USD     857.14                                                      
 CHI LH X/FRA LH GDN86.85KKNC2N/CN10 LO X/FRA LH CHI86.85KKNC2N/                 
 CN10 NUC173.70END ROE1.000000 XF ORD4.5                                         

 55.FE REFTHRUAG/NONEND/NONRERTE/LH/UA/AC/OS/SN/LX ONLY -BG:LH
```

59.FM *M*0
 60.FP CHECK
";

now i create a function where i use my coding part like this:

```
public class Detail
{
    string output;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;
     public DataTable GetDetail(List<string> request, List<string> Request)
     {
            string item = data;
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"(FXP\S{3,20})|(\r\s{3}.\S+(.+))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
            foreach (Match m in regex1.Matches(data))
            {
                output = m.ToString();
            }
               dr["Passenger Name"] = output;
             }
            return dt; 
           }
     }
```

in this i get result in the same row like the below screenshot
[image]

in 2nd row their are two name i want each name in different row like this

[image]

but not number and .

Thanks in advance

Comment: I edit the string and according to that string my regex work in my regex it fetch name from the string but it fetch those name in series what i want is to take name without number, . and space into gridview in row wise manner

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your RegEx but this works as far as I've tested:

```
Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"(?<=\d\.)([^\s]*)(?=\s)");
```

or use:

```
Regex.Split(string, @"\s*\d\.\s*");
```

Comment: basically this regex is only used for my code sry i didn't mention it

Comment: your regex work fine but i have a list of string not only single string and when i use ur regex it match other than name to

Comment: What else does it match? Try to be more specific and I'll try to craft more suitable regex.

Comment: wait let me paste few more string to you

Comment: @filipko:- your regex is good but It matches number,dot's and spaces also.

Comment: @Anurag Jain It doesn't match spaces. It matches substrings without spaces starting with number and dot and followed by space.

Comment: Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"(FXP\S{3,20})|(\r\s{3}.\S+(.+))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
                foreach (Match m in regex1.Matches(data))
                {
                    output2 = m.ToString();
                }
                string[] out1 = Regex.Split(output2, @"(?<=\d\.)([^\s]*)(?=\s)"); i used your regex like this but in place if i have two name this code should give me two index value but it give 4 index value with number

Comment: @amitesh Don't use Regex.Split, it works differently. Use Regex.Match. Does this work for you?

Comment: @filipko try this code code with debugger you will get to know

Comment: @filipko i don't want whole string to be match so i take all names into output2 and then split that ouput2 and store it in out1 and show it in the gridview i hope you understand what i m trying to say

Comment: but the thing is that when i split names by using your regex for two name i get 4 index value not 2 mate\

Comment: @amitesh That's because Regex.Split method splits your string instead of matching the names. If you want to use Split method, use `Regex.Split(output2, @"\s*\d\.\s*");`

Comment: thanks mate your regex work fine i have to make some changes in my code once i do that i will get back to you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29725/discussion-between-amitesh-and-filipko)